# How to convert android.net.Uri to java.net.URL?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to convert from `Uri` to `URL`? I need this for a library I'm using, it *only* accepts an `URL` but I need to use an image on my device.

Comment: `new URL(uri.toString())` ?

Comment: That works.... I'm sorry, I never thought that would work, I thought I had to do a method conversion.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If the scheme of the `Uri` is `http` or `https`, `new URL(uri.toString())` should work.

If the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, that may still also work, though I get nervous.

If the scheme of the `Uri` is `ftp` or `jar`, that may still also work, though we will wonder why you have a `Uri` with those schemes.

If the scheme of the `Uri` is anything else — such as `content` — this will not work, and you need to find a better library.

Answer (score 7):

**Try this**

```
android.net.URI auri = new android.net.URI("your url goes here");
java.net.URI juri = new java.net.URI(auri.toString());
```

**For more refer:**

[Android Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

[Java URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

Comment: new android.net.Uri is abstract class, use   android.net.Uri.parse("you url")