# How to load url image to bitmap, convert it to drawable and display it with imageview

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

I have a `uri` of image from `firebase` but i don't know how to load it into bitmap, because i needed to cut the four corner edge of the image.

I tried it with `resource id` by providing drawable icon and it does worked fine, but not working from `uri`

Below is my code:

```
        uri imagefile = model.getImageUri();

        if (imagefile !=null){

        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        Resources res = c.getResources();

        //How i'm loading the image
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, 
        Integer.parseInt(imagefile)); 


        RoundedBitmapDrawable dr =
        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, src);
        dr.setCornerRadius(Math.max(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()) / 
        30.0f);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(dr);

    }
```

How to load image using `uri`? It will help me to solve other related issues as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use AsyncTask to keep the process at the background so as to not lag the UI:

**ImageLoadAsyncTask.java**

```
public class ImageLoadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ImageLoadAsyncTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        this.url = url;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**Then, use this codeto load your image from Firebase:**

```
ImageLoadAsyncTask imageLoadAsyncTask = new ImageLoadAsyncTask(url, imageView);
 imageLoadAsyncTask.execute();
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can check how to convert Uri to Url in this (watch the answer of CommonsWare)

[How to convert android.net.Uri to java.net.URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945809/how-to-convert-android-net-uri-to-java-net-url)

And this it how to load bitmap from URL (watch the answer of rajath)

[Load image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Comment: Thanks. I tried his answer, but i got error because the code is running on main thread. and i looked down for another answer, another answer improved his own, but i don't how to use it with my code.